# Could pure iron from a star make it to Earth?

Tags: supernova, meteor

Since iron is a stars waste could a star that goes Super nova eject pure iron to travel across the galaxy?

https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35101/99-99-pure-iron-meteorite

Comment: It already has :-)

Comment: You link to a closed post (that went through numerous revisions before being [edited down to a non-question](https://web.archive.org/web/20191031205546/https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/35101/revisions)) posted by someone who thinks they have a nearly pure iron meteorite. What is the purpose of the link? Are you asking whether an iron chunk of that mass (a reported 4,902 grams) and that reported purity (99.99%) could be directly ejected by a supernova?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Iron is not made in significant quantities in the Big Bang, so 100% of the iron on Earth today was synthesized in a star. There's no other source.

It escapes in many ways:

- Supernovae
- Mergers between compact stars like white dwarfs and neutron stars
- Stellar winds from more ordinary stars

Supernovae are the main source of modern-day iron, with r-process nucleosynthesis during the explosion producing a *lot* of iron and elements near iron.

Comment: What do you think about the linked question?

Comment: I don't know enough about meteoritics to speak intelligently -- sorry! (Mineralogy was never a favorite subject.)

Comment: Mass spectrometry may tell the tale: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001AGUFM.V21A0959K

Comment: The question isn't asking whether iron is produced in supernovae. You seem to be agreeing with the premise of the question.